# How to plot custom symbols over a basemap in Python

Tags: python

I have a shapefile layer of points and I would like to plot them using a particular symbol. In particular my data refers to some shelters in Poland and I would like to visualize them using the OCHA humanitarian icon found at the link below:

https://brand.unocha.org/d/xEPytAUjC3sH/icons

Basically that icon can be dowloaded in PNG or SVG format.

Actually I am using
cartopy and matplotlib, in the code below I'm showing how I plotted those points using a basic pentagon marker

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader


import matplotlib.patheffects as pe
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt



# projection of the layers
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

request = cimgt.OSM()
ax = plt.axes(projection = request.crs) # OSM proj is mercator as I wanted 

# set regione xtent
region = [16, 35, 44, 53] #xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
ax.set_extent(region)

# add osm 
ax.add_image(request, 8)

# possibility to add some feature
ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, lw=2)
ax.add_feature(cf.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cf.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE,linewidth=0.3)
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, linestyle=':',linewidth=0.3)
ax.add_feature(cf.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cf.RIVERS)

# Make figure larger
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20, 10)


def read_poly(path):
    reader = shpreader.Reader(path)
    polygons = [i for i in reader.records()]

    return polygons

# open and plot boundaries
boundaries_p = r"C:\Users\Giorg\Desktop\prova\countries.shp"

bounds = read_poly(boundaries_p)
for i in bounds:
    shape_feature = ShapelyFeature([i.geometry], proj, facecolor='none', 
edgecolor='black', lw=2)
ax.add_feature(shape_feature)



# open shelters
rec_p = r"C:\Users\Giorg\Desktop\prova\2022_03_02_POL_Reception_Centres.shp"
rec = gpd.read_file(rec_p)

# plot sheleters as pentagons...
plt.scatter(
    x = rec.Lon,
    y = rec.Lat,
    marker = 'p',
    color = "none",
    edgecolors="blue",
    linewidths = 0.8,
    s = 200,
    alpha = 1,
    transform = proj
)

out = r"C:\Users\Giorg\Desktop\prova.png"

print('saving fig')
plt.savefig(out, dpi = 300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The result is something like that:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion on how should I plot the shelter icon from OCHA in place of the pentagons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://petercbsmith.github.io/marker-tutorial.html) explains how to convert an .svg file to a matplotlib Path object, which can be used in the scatter command.